# Why doesn't my object property function increment when called into a "new" operator via variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out why calling a function from an object value directly inside a "new" operator works as desired (creates a unique incremental id integer for the "same" object):

```
var allItems = [];
var item;
var idid = 0;

function generateId() {
  return idid += 1;
}

function create(){
  var item = new NewItem( {id: generateId(), punch: 10, kick: 5} );
  allItems.push(item);
  console.log (allItems);
}

function NewItem(item) {
  this.item = item;
}
```

But calling the same function from an object value within a variable that is then brought into the "new" operator does not work in the same way (continuously returns the number "1").

```
var allItems = [];
var item;
var idid = 0;


function generateId() {
  return idid += 1;
}

function create(){
  var item = new NewItem(coolObject);
  allItems.push(item);
  console.log (allItems);
}

function NewItem(item) {
  this.item = item;
}

var coolObject = {id: generateId(), punch: 10, kick: 5};
```

This can be demonstrated by creating the same object several times in each example via:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="create()">CREATE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried indenting your code to make it readable?

Comment: where do you call create? - you know after running the code coolObject is `{
  "id": 1,
  "punch": 10,
  "kick": 5
}` and `idid` is 1 ... so .. it works, yay

Comment: I did give that a shot. Sadly it didn't help at all. (Thanks @Dez, my copy paste from DW lost my indents).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally got it...

Need to put the 'external' var object in its own object (which is cool, this is where you can list out all your items in a neat and fashionable way) like so:

```
var everyItems = {
  coolObject: {punch: 10, kick: 5},
  neatoObject: {swipe: 7, scratch: 2},
};
```

Then you still need to call that generateId function directly within the new constructor (I never figured out a way around this) but now put the id generator along side the new item you're creating like so:

```
function create(){
  var item = new NewItem( {id: generateId()}, coolObject );
  allItems.push(item);
}
```

Then here is where the true resolution to my problem comes in, in the actual constructor function you merge the uniquely generated ID with the new item you are creating...

```
function NewItem(item, coolObject) {
    this.item = item;
    Object.assign(item, coolObject);
}
```

Fire off create() a bunch-o-times and you'll get a bunch of identical "coolObjects" EXCEPT they will have unique ID's.

```
// item: {id: 1, punch: 10, kick: 5}
// item: {id: 2, punch: 10, kick: 5}
// item: {id: 3, punch: 10, kick: 5}
// item: {id: 4, punch: 10, kick: 5}
```

To recap, I was doing exactly what I wanted by including the new object properties, including the generateId() function, directly in the new operator variable (like my first example) - but this meant I would have had to code a create item function for each individual new, different, or same (but with unique ID) type of item. a dozen? hundred? thousand?

So needed to get the functionality (unique ID with matching objects) to work with an external object.

TL;DR
generate the unique ID separately, pass in the external object (with all of its properties) and merge them together with Object.assign.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, you call `generateId()` multiple times which increments the id, in the second case you call it just once. That has nothing todo with the new constructor call, it can be easily reproduced with:

```
 // works:

 let obj = { id: generateId() }; // first call
 console.log(obj) // { id: 1 }
 let obj2 = { id: generateId() }; // second call
 console.log(obj2); // { id: 2 }

 // "doesnt work":

 let obj = { id: generateId() }; // first call
 console.log(obj) // { id: 1 }
 console.log(obj) // { id: 1 }
```

Comment: Not quite. In your "working" example you are having to give the object a new variable name in order to get a new id to stick. I am not doing that in either of my examples. To the contrary I am making the "same" object over and over again (more like your second example) but each time it **does** successfully get a new unique Id property. I am now trying to achieve the same success but by creating the new object via a variable (that contains an object with properties) instead of having to pump the properties directly into the new operator variable (which works as desired).